# how to manually rewrite wordpress url

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I installed an affiliate plugin in WordPress and its affiliate link looks like
http://website.com/?affiliate=1

I want to make this link like  http://website.com/1

I tried to edit the .htaccess file with

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?affiliate=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?affiliate=$1
```

but it doesn't worked .. 
there is any other solution to do this ?